# How to export function defined by eval?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Define a dynamic function by running this in command line:

```
eval "ab() { echo test; }"
```

It runs and prints test.

Put the same statement in a script `test.sh` and then execute the script. Nothing happens. The function does not get defined.

I assume that is because function gets defined within script but not outside it. 
So I try adding within the script:

```
export -f ab
```

But it doesn't work. How do I export functions from a script to the shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't export a function or a variable to a parent shell, you can only export to the shell running the script or to child shells.

For a script to change the environment of your current shell, you need to run the script with `source` or `.`.  e.g. instead of running `./myscript.sh`, you'd run `. ./myscript.sh`

This tells your current shell to run the script itself, rather than spawning a sub-shell to run it in...and thus allows the script to modify the current environment.

Comment: You cannot export functions to shell descendents. A shell that permits you to do so must be seen as a security risk ans this permits code injection.

Comment: Whether you *should* or not does not change the fact that you *can* export a function in `bash`.